# Visual Studio Debugger Watch problems

Tags: c++, native, visual-studio-debugging

How can I find out the address of a variable on the stack in the visual studio debugger watch window (or elsewhere?)

Reading the variable works fine:

```
streets     streets [11790](0x1c66a690 [...] std::vector<Street *,std::allocator<Street *> >
```

But prefixing with & doesn't give me an address:

```
&streets        streets [11790](0x1c66a690 [...] std::vector<Street *,std::allocator<Street *> >
```

Also, trying to read the size doesn't work, why is that?

```
streets.size()  CXX0075: Error: Cannot set up Function Evaluation
```

The program is compiled in debug mode.

Comment: &streets should give you pointer to your variable, I doubt watch window can execute functions like vector::size().

Comment: @marcin_j:  It can, actually.  The VS watch window is quite powerful.

Comment: @JohnDibling nice, I will have to check it with my VS2005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Visual Studio Debugger drives debugger watch, quick-watch, auto, and local variable views through a translation defined by schema in a file called **autoexp.dat** (depending on your VS version, the content therein can vary markedly). The file is located in your VS-InstallDir/Common7/Packages/Debugger folder (at least it is for VS2010 and VS2012).

Knowing this, a couple of ideas for you to try/consider:

**Method One: Library Know-How**

To access the actual *address* of the first element *within* the vector I ultimately just do this:

```
streets._Myfirst
```

if you know the number of elements you're going to view, you can use the array-expansion extension by:

```
streets._Myfirst,N
```

where `N` is the number of elements

Note: this only works as shown above with vectors. The practice is different depending on which container you are using. There are no-doubt simpler ways that are probably less dependent on the implementation of std::vector<>, but this is the simplest wasy I know how to get you up and debugging quickly.

---

**Method Two: Scorched Earth**

Under Tools/Options/Debugging/General is a list of features you can switch on and off. One of them you will find particularly useful to this question:

> Show raw structure of objects in variable windows.

Turn this **ON** to see raw member variables of **all** structures and containers, including standard containers like std::vector<>. This effectively disables usage of the templates in **autoexp.dat**

Comment: Method one works well thanks.  Of course the vector size can then be retrieved by entering `streets._Mylast - streets._Myfirst`.  Not sure why `vector::size()` doesn't work but pah who needs it.

Answer (score 4):

To see the address, cast to a `void *`, like so: `(void *)&streets`.

This is Visual Studio's attempt to be helpful by showing you the pointed-to vector directly. A similar problem affects arrays of vectors.